# How to switch input languages with different key combination?

Tags: keyboard

I don't like to switch languages with <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd>. Is there any way I can use more common keyboard combinations:

- <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> or
- <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Opion</kbd> or
- <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>

I'd preferred the simplest solution possible. Can I just change some system settings instead of installing a software to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already use [PuntoSwitcher](http://punto.yandex.ru/) which does the trick but it has some annoying bugs and it's  **only useful for russian-speaking users** because UI is only in russian. That's why I want to find an alternative.

The main purpose of [PuntoSwitcher](http://punto.yandex.ru/) is to fixe words typed with wrong keyboard layout. For example:

```
руддщ → hello
ghbdtn → привет
```

So it may be useful for somebody who uses russian a lot (outsourcing managers, people who learn russian, etc).

Comment: Are there BETTER alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the key combination via **System Preferences → Keyboard → Keyboard Shortcuts** → Keyboard & Text Input:

[image: Screenshot]

The settings you’re looking for are the last two in the list: *“Select the previous input source”* and *“Select next source in Input menu”*.

Comment: The problem is that it's impossible to put ANY of listed in my question key kombinations there. When you click with your mouse on key combination you can replace default "⌘ + Space" with something like "⌘ + B" but nice key combinations are deliberately forbiden :(